# Docker swarm loses managers?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Running a 5 node swarm. Some time ago I lost my single manager and had to re init a new swarm. To avoid loosing everything again I promoted 3 nodes out of the 5 this time.

Now the cluster has just been sitting for 6 month (running nothing real important). All 5 nodes now reports that they are not managers. Somehow all the managers have been auto demoted. All nodes still belong to the cluster but no manager is present.

Why is this happening? It seems a bit unreliable.

Comment: Do you have access to docker engine logs? Could you please publish it? You should be checking for the logs from last “Leader” Node.

Comment: Educated guess: your machines are vms and you had them turned off the whole time. If so, the validity of the nodes certificates expired after 90 days (default, unless manualy changed) without beeing able to rotate the certificates and replace them with new valid ones.

Comment: Nope it is raspberry pi's and they have been on constantly. They could potentially have been restarted (lost power) a couple of time. I checked the logs but I guess the default retention is 30 days and there was nothing in the logs that stood out as source of the problem.